# Making position: sticky work for 100% of page height (not just viewport height)

Tags: css, flexbox, sticky

I'm working on a page that is, essentially, an article template. The article has a social sharing feature on it--facebook, twitter, email, print, etc. That container, we'll call it the Social Share container, needs to be sticky when the user scrolls.

I currently have the solution only partially working. I can get the container to be sticky for 100vh, but when the height of the viewport scrolls off screen, the container's height is exceeded and the container stops being sticky (it has hit the bottom of it's containing element's height).

```
.parent-element {
height: 100vh;
position: absolute;
display: block (user style sheet);
}
.sticky-element {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
align-items: start;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}
.sticky-children {
align-self: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: That's just how 'sticky' works - it's limited to its parent element. You're probably looking for 'fixed' positioning.

Comment: So I'm assuming I need a way to make the parent element height == page height. I want sticky because I want it to only start 'sticking' when the top of the sticky container hits the top of the viewport.

Comment: Sticky positioning still leaves the element in the document flow, so it'll interfere with anything below it as it 'scrolls' down the page. Unless that's what you want, you need fixed positioning.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what I want. Fixed positioning isn't to work, as far as I'm aware, because I want it to be a third of the way down the page until the user scrolls and the top of the sticky container is at the top of the viewport, then I want it to 'stick' to the viewport top. Fixed means just that--it would stay 1/3 of the way down the page all the time, which isn't what I want.

Comment: Then you'll have to make the `<body>` element the parent of the sticky element. If you can't do that, then you'll have to add a scroll event listener to convert the object to 'fixed' only when the page's scroll offset exceeds the element's offset - that'll achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Put overflow-y-auto on parent div it will be sticky even if it exceeds 100vh , it worked for me like that